# Close a chrome browser window opened by batch file

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, batch-file

I have a simple batch script on the server that opens an instance of chrome and a url address using some javascript as well.

The above is working fine but I am then trying to close the browser after 30 seconds.

I have installed PSKill but my batch code is not working.

Do I have to specify the full path or something to the pskill.exe file?

Thanks for all relevant replies.

```
@echo off
start chrome.exe javascript:document. http://google.com
TIMEOUT 30
PSKILL chrome.exe
```

Comment: try using taskkill: `taskkill /IM chrome.exe /T` the `/T` is necessary because chrome spawns quite a few child processes. Also, try your commands in the cmd shell first..

Answer (score 1):

taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe /T > nul

"> nul" needs to suppress error messages, preventing getting roped into a dialog

Comment: this is already indicated in very old comments. If it's not answered that's because the comments already answered it.